# Check if value is in returned value of function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function that returns a single element in most cases. In  a particular case it returns a vector. How to efficiently check if a given value is present in the returned value/values of the function.?

```
for i=1:n

x=somefunc(data)
//now x could be single value or vector
//say k single value, k=5. 
if(k==x)  // This works if x is single value. What to do in case x is vector.?
//do something
end
// k value changes in every loop, so does x.
end
```

Comment: You just want to use the [any](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function. so `if any(k==x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use

```
ismember(value, array)
```

If you want it to be fast, the best thing to do is try alternative options and profile it. The best solution will depend on how often your function returns a vector as opposed to a scalar. Here are a couple of options:

```
// Use ismember on every iteration
if ismember(k, x)
  // do things
end

// Use any on every iteration
if any(k==x)
  // do thing
end

// Check if you have a scalar value, call ismember if not
if isscalar(x) && k==x || ismember(k,x)
  // do things
end

// Check if you have a scalar value, call any if not
if isscalar(x) && k==x || any(k==x)
  // do things
end
```

You can turn the profiler on with `profile on`, run the function, and then look at the results with `profile viewer`. Alternatively you can do some simpler timings with `tic` and `toc`.

Comment: x is mostly a single valued except in one case. Won't using this function always be inefficient.? Btw, the above code is in for loop in my code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very very vague question. do you mean this:

```
value = 5;
array = [1 5 4 6 7];

any(array==value)
```